# Why is my page ranked *very* low in Google?

Tags: search-engines, google-search, search-results

I have created a web site [mianatura.net](http://mianatura.net) that doesn't even rank in the top 100 results in Google for the query "Mia Natura".

I have the text Mia Natura in the domain, `<title>`, `<h1>`, I have the site in Google Webmaster Tools, the site *is* crawled (finding 172 results for `site:mianatura.net`).

I have checked my standing manually (going through the SERPs), using [What Page of Search Am I on](http://whatpageofsearchamion.com/) and [diyseo](http://www.diyseo.com/).

The site is not involved in any dubious link building campaigns (as far as I know). So what's going on?

Comment: Why was this page closed? It's not relevant only to a small geographic area or a specific moment in time. Everyone that creates a new website for mycompany.com can run into this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, how long did your website spent online?
It takes some time and a lot of efforts to see your website in the first positions especially when there are competitors.

Try sharing your URL with friends and on forums, try bringing different IP's and backlinks to your website too.

Choose carefully the keywords and try keeping a unique URL too for the website.

Comment: It's been there for a couple of weeks, so yes, it's maybe too early. But one other site that we launched came straight to first page (#6).

Comment: I guess so too.